# How can the struct specialized atomic type be lock free?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I found the following code, the out put is always:

```
std::atomic<A> is lock free? false
std::atomic<B> is lock free? true
```

This is the code:

```
struct A { int a[100]; };
struct B { int x, y; };
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << "std::atomic<A> is lock free? "
              << std::atomic<A>{}.is_lock_free() << '\n'
              << "std::atomic<B> is lock free? "
              << std::atomic<B>{}.is_lock_free() << '\n';
}
```

I do not understand how can the second struct specialized atomic type be lock free and the 1st specialized atomic type cannot be lock free?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably your hardware is capable of executing atomic instructions on a sufficient width that can hold two `int`s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_is_lock_free really explains it in the comment section. Memory alignment and register size may allow 2 packed ints to be handled in atomic way. In other word, 2 aligned ints are not different than a single long long on a 64bit system with 128bit register.

Answer (score 2):

`std::atomic` requires its template argument to be trivially copyable. That is, it knows that (load, store, etc.) operations on your struct `B` simply copy bytes, and can be done with appropriate atomic instructions, if they are wide enough.

Comment: What has this to do with lockfreeness?

Comment: @KerrekSB Due to trivial copyability the compiler can support lock-free operations on the atomic type provided that the architecture has sufficiently wide atomic instructions. If a copy constructor needed to be called then in general I don't think the compiler could figure out how to make it lock-free.

Comment: OK, but this is somewhat derailing, because the OP's counterexample is also trivial...